# What does it mean with real manifold with complex structure?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, complex-geometry

For example on wikipedia I found that one can also define a Hermitian manifold as a real manifold with a Riemannian metric that preserves a complex structure.

For real manifold it should be understood a manifold with real charts, i.e., diffeomorphisms from an open subsets of M and open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then what does it mean with complex structure? is only the complexification of its tangent space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sense, a complex structure is an endomorphism of the tangent bundle $J:TM\to TM$ such that $J^2=-1$ (it plays the role of the multiplication by $\sqrt{-1}$). Saying that a Riemannian metric $g$ preserves the complex structure amounts to saying that $g(Jv,Jv)=g(v,v)$ for all tangent vector $v$.

Note that this forces the (real) dimension of $M$ to be even, and that if $M$ is a complex manifold, taking holomorphic charts $(U,\varphi=(z^1,\dots,z^n)=(x^1,y^1,\dots,x^n,z^n))$ and defining locally a $J_0:TM\to TM$ by $J_0(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i})=\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}$ and $J_0(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i})=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ defines a canonical complex structure.

Moreover, given any $J$, the complexification of the (real) tangent bundle of $M$ is written as $TM\otimes\mathbb{C}:=T_\mathbb{C}M=T^{(1,0)}M\oplus T^{(0,1)}M$ where $T^{(1,0)}M$ is the vector bundle associated to the eigenvalue $i$ of $J_\mathbb{C}$ (where $J_\mathbb{C}(v\otimes z)=J(v)\otimes z$) and $T^{(0,1)}M$ is the vector bundle associated to the eigenvalue $-i$ of $J$. Thus you have a $\mathbb{C}$-linear isomorphism between $(TM,J)$ and $T^{(1,0)}M$ as complex bundles (and a $\mathbb{C}$-antilinear one between $(TM,J)$ and $T^{(0,1)}M$).

Comment: Why $M$ must be even-dimension?

Comment: Because each $J_p:T_pM\to T_pM$ is an endomorphism such that $(\det\,J_p)^2=\det (J_p^2)=\det(-1)=(-1)^{\dim T_pM}=(-1)^{\dim M}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! And being that $M$ is real with Riemannian metric$g=E(u,v)du^2+G(u,v)dv^2$, which is its complex version on the complexificated tangent space? Maybe something like $g=E(u,v)[\frac{1}{2}(du+d\bar{u})]^2-G(u,v)[\frac{1}{2}(dv - d\bar{v})]^2$ ?

Comment: Hmm I don't know, only thing I know from there is that you can get an hermitian metric from $g$ setting $h(u,v)=\frac{1}{2}(g(u,v)+g(Ju,Jv))$, but it is still at the real level and I don't know how to get something at the complex level.

Comment: Not every metric can be put in hermitian metric form, is correct? For example the metric $g=udu^2+u^5dv^2$ is impossible to put in hermitian form, is correct? Then this means that the real manifold $M$ with that real metric, does not preserve the complex structure. Is right?

Comment: Yes, this is right: your real metric $g$ has to preserve the complex structure in order to give an hermitian one when defining $h(u,v) :=g(u,v)-ig(Ju,v)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Last thing, for example if $g=(4u^2+1)du^2+(4v^2+1)dv^2$ which is its Hermitian form?

Answer (score 1):

Let me say that I do not know too much about differential geometry, but I think I can still answer that question.

Two complex atlases $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ on some topological space $X$ are called equivalent, when $\mathcal{A} \cup \mathcal{B}$ once again is an atlas. Using Zorn's lemma one can show that every atlas is contained in a unique maximal atlas (namely the atlas defined as the union of all equivalent atlases). A maximal atlas is also called complex structure.

That way you can for example define a riemann surface as non-empty connected real $2$-manifold equipped with a complex structure instead of defining it as a complex manifold.